# Incorrect sum of rows in HTML table using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am stuck with getting the correct total revenue (total Media Cost, total Revenue, and total Profit) for each month. I have created a plunker for the same. Can you, please, help?

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/7taIugnhGPZbqCMGpUza?p=preview

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('AppController',['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.total = function(i){
      var totalMediaCost = 0;
      var totalRevenue = 0;
      var totalProfit = 0;
      $scope.array = [];
        console.log('i.revenue', i.revenue);
        for (var data in i.revenue){
          console.log('data', data);
          totalMediaCost += i.revenue[data].a;
          totalRevenue += i.revenue[data].b;
          totalProfit += i.revenue[data].c;

        } 
      $scope.array.push({'totalMediaCost': totalMediaCost});

    }

    $scope.rows = [
    {
      "month": "Feb-01",
      "revenue": [
        {
          "account": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "user alpha"
        },
          "a": 111,
          "b": 222,
          "c": 333
        },
        {
          "account": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "user beta"
        },
          "a": 1,
          "b": 2,
          "c": 3,
        },
        {
          "account": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "user gamma"
        },
          "a": 141,
          "b": 242,
          "c": 343
        }
      ]
     },
     {
      "month": "Mar-02",
      "revenue": [
      {
        "account": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "user alpha"
      },
        "a": 100,
        "b": 200,
        "c": 300
      },
      {
        "account": {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "user beta"
      },
        "a": 101,
        "b": 202,
        "c": 303
      },
      {
        "account": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "user gamma"
      },
        "a": 241,
        "b": 342,
        "c": 443
      }
     ]
    }
  ];

  }
]
);
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">

  {{rows | json}}

  <hr>

  <table class="table">

    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Media Cost</th>
      <th>Revenue</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng:repeat="i in rows">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{i.revenue.length+1}}">{{i.month}}</td>
        <tr ng:repeat="data in i.revenue">
          <td>{{data.account.name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.a}}</td>
          <td>{{data.b}}</td>
          <td>{{data.c}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-init="total(i)">
          <td></td>
          <td>Total Revenue</td>
          <td>{{array[0].totalMediaCost}}</td>
          <td>{{}}</td>
          <td>{{}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/bB7up1rhOSad9Xoq3SsQ?p=preview

---

Its better to use the existing `rows` array and push the total inside each row object rather than creating a separate variable in scope.

---

```
$scope.total = function(i,index) {
    $scope.rows[index].totalMediaCost = totalMediaCost;
}
```

---

```
<tr ng-init="total(i,$index)">
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same variable twice, wich gives you the totalMediaCost of the last array for both tables

you should change the totalMediaCost to an array or similar

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your approach a little. Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukWEcy5MU6IDGDL1uInD?p=preview).

JS:

```
$scope.total = {
    cost : [],
    revenue : [],
    profit : []
  };

  for (var month in $scope.rows) {
    if ($scope.rows.hasOwnProperty(month)) {
      var revData = $scope.rows[month]["revenue"],
          totalCost = 0,
          totalRevenue = 0,
          totalProfit = 0;

      revData.forEach(function (account) {
        totalCost += account["a"];
        totalRevenue += account["b"];
        totalProfit += account["c"];
      });

      $scope.total.cost.push(totalCost);
      $scope.total.revenue.push(totalRevenue);
      $scope.total.profit.push(totalProfit);
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<tbody ng:repeat="i in rows">
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="{{i.revenue.length+1}}">{{i.month}}</td>
      <tr ng:repeat="data in i.revenue">
        <td>{{data.account.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.a}}</td>
        <td>{{data.b}}</td>
        <td>{{data.c}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>{{total.cost[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{total.revenue[$index]}}</td>
        <td>{{total.profit[$index]}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
```